# Java List.add() and Map.put()

Tags: java, addition, put, difference

Working with `Lists` and `Maps`, I started thinking, why Map method for adding `Object` is called **put** and for List it is `add`?

It is just developers will, or there was something under naming those methods different.

May be the methods names let the developer know while adding to `Map`/`List` what kind of data structure he is working with?
Or those names describes the way they works?

Comment: To differentiate

Comment: That's how they designed the language.

Comment: Question is not about why those methods have names, but why they practically acting same way, are called different

Comment: `add()` can be seen that you add it to the end of something, whereas with `put()` you place your value at the position where the key is (this is not the real implementation)

Comment: `Map.put` and `List.add` do very different things. Saying they practically act the same way is simply incorrect.

Comment: `put` can replace a value (if the key was already associated with a value), whereas `add` always only adds a value to a list

Comment: @UnholySheep And the `add` method in `Set`can do nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is :

1. .add() means to insert something at the end or wherever you want to(you know where to add) whereas
2. .put() means to add an element wherever it needs to be placed, not necessarily at the end of the Map, because it all depends on the Key to be inserted (you don't know where to add).

Comment: technically not true. [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-) isn't limited to end of the list.

Comment: Well of course after that it depends on the parameters, you can add at the beginning or wherever you want, But, with put, you don't know where to insert actually.  And thanks for the note @Tezra!

Answer (score 2):

To me, it has some cause.
After all, List is a dynamic array, which internally consists a logical index where we are adding.
And map internally carry a bucket of key and value pair. So kind of we are putting something into the bucket.

It can be stated as so because to get a clear understanding.
As java is a 3rd level human understandable language this also can state as a simple English for better understanding.

Comment: `List` is an interface, `ArrayList` is the one that uses an array

Answer (score 1):

`Collection#add()` can be seen that you add your value to a pool of something (an implementation of `Collection<E>` defines what *pool* actually is).

Whereas with `Map#put()` you associate your value with the key which potentially already had a value associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

For this you should just read the Java docs for [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) and [put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-).

They are 2 different function, that take completely incompatible inputs, and return completely incompatible values. They are 2 completely separate and distinct functions that behave completely differently (other than they both are for adding elements to a collection (the concept, not interface. As map doesn't implement that interface)).

From the docs

**PUT**

Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value. (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)

**ADD**

Appends the specified element to the end of this list (optional operation).
Lists that support this operation may place limitations on what elements may be added to this list. In particular, some lists will refuse to add null elements, and others will impose restrictions on the type of elements that may be added. List classes should clearly specify in their documentation any restrictions on what elements may be added.

Answer (score 1):

Add will always add an entry to the end of a list.

Put injects an entry into the map if the key does not already exist; if the key already exists, the value is updated.

Thus the operations are different. On some level, the authors of the API have to make decisions that balance out various concerns. Add to a set has some aspects of add to a list and put to a map, in that adding an "equal" entry has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

List :- If i say i'm adding some items to the some Container ill say that i have added the items to the container.Here we are more concentrate on the new item Addition to the existing **container** or **List** (in java).

Map :- If i want to put some of the things to the some `locker` or my computer which is already having the things which i dont care about i just have to put not add.
Here we are concentrate to addition of new data to the locker or `Map` (in java) regardless of existing the thing.

Real time example:-  you add sugar to the tea keeping in mind the amount which is already their.you put your cloths to the Clothing Store regarding their exist any cloths or not.

In java side :- 
if you list is like this :-

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("java");
        list.add("php");
        list.add("python");
        list.add("perl");
        list.add("c");
        list.add("lisp");
        list.add("c#");
```

and you want to add something to the list you have to care about the existing thing because if it is `list` it will add duplicate and if set then don't duplicate.
If you create a Map.

```
Map<String, Object> foodData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    foodData.put("penguin", 1);
    foodData.put("flamingo", 2);
```

and again you are adding something `foodData.put("penguin", 3);` you don't have to worry about adding and update the data internally.

Comment: Yours example with tea, sugar and List, more remind me a map, quantity of sugar each time being updated in the key(cup)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you get into etymology we can only guess that since when you place a value into a list you always increase the list length, however if you put the value into a map you would not necessary increase the number of map entries (if the key already exists)